# Таблицу адаптировать как?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Скажите пожалуйста как сделать таблицу адаптивной ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например table-responsive в Bootsrap. Очень удобная вещь http://getbootstrap.ru/docs/v4-alpha/content/tables/#responsive-tables

Comment: Зависит правда от таблицы на самом деле, насколько она большая

Comment: Так как таблицу, как правило, нельзя перестроить вертикально, как остальные блоки, то необходимо на мобильных устр-вах медиазапросами скрывать самые незначителные колонки. Ну а в остальном, как обычно(меньши шрифт, меньши паддинги/марджины и т.д.) 
Ну или можете извратиться и попробовать сделать фреймами(тег frame), тогда у вас, по идеи, будет горизонтальная полоса прокрутки для таблицы)